# Checkbox styled as non-checkbox- need label to fill row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal where the user can do multiple choices. For the multiple choices, I have used checkboxes. But I do not want them shown as checkboxes, rather I want it to where when the user clicks on a selection it highlights.

I styled it to look like this by having the checkbox enlarged, positioned over the `label`, and gave the `opacity 0` to the checkbox. This works out good.

I want the whole row of the selection to fill with color. So, if the user clicked on `foobar` and `foo`, both would be high lighted red with no white space in between.

Right now, I am having a issue getting the `label` to fill the row area. I don't want squash the spaces between the selections. How can I get the `label` to fill the row area with the background color red when selected?

http://codepen.io/dman777/pen/MbqPeZ

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - this is what you're looking for

```
.goals-multiselect {
  div {
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]{width:100%;}
  label {margin:0;line-height:40px;}
}    

input[type="checkbox"] {
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVRgvY

Comment: Close! But I want to keep the spaces(rows with more height) between the selections.... I want to be able to fill those with color also when selected

Comment: Increase the line-height of label to 40px or so

Comment: Thanks! That did it! Looks like `line-height:40px` was the key!